# How to rigorously show that elementary operations on polygonal presentations yields homeomorphic spaces?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces, polygons

In Lee's book *Introduction to Topological Manifolds*, he discusses elementary operations on polygonal presentations. Before the question, here are the terminologies that I am going to be using:

---

- A *polygonal presentation*, written $\mathcal{P}=\left<S\mid W_1,\dots ,W_k\right>$, is a finite set $S$ together with finitely many words $W_1,\dots ,W_k,$ in $S$ of length $3$ or more, such that every symbol in $S$ appears at least once in one word. (He also discusses the special case where $S$ is a singleton set and there is only one word of length $2$, but since it is irrelevant to this question, I will omit it.)
- The *geometric realization* $\mid \mathcal{P} \mid$ of a given polygonal presentation $\mathcal{P}=\left<S\mid W_1,\dots ,W_k\right>$ is defined as follows:
  For each $W_i$, let $P_i$ denote the regular $n_i$-gon in the plane.(Here $n_i$
  is the length of $W_i$.) Define a one-to-one correspondence between the symbols of $W_i$ and the edges of $P_i$ in counterclockwise order, and then let $\sim$ be the smallest equivalence relation $P=\coprod P_i$ that identifies the edges that have the same label. We define $\mid \mathcal{P}\mid$ to be the quotient space $P/\sim$.
- Two polygonal presentations are said to be equivalent if their geometric realizations are homeomorphic.

---

Let us get back to the question. In the book, the author claims that certain operations on polygonal presentations yield equivalent presentations. For instance, the operation called *folding*, which is
$$\mathcal {P}=\left<S\mid W_1ee^{-1},\dots ,W_k\right> \mapsto \mathcal{P}'=\left<S,e\mid W_1,\dots ,W_k\right>,$$
produces equivalent presentations. The basic idea of the proof of why this is true is outlined in the book; it goes like this:

Let $q:P=\coprod P_i \to \mid\mathcal{P} \mid$ and $q':P'=\coprod P'_i\to \mid\mathcal{P}' \mid$ are the quotient maps corresponding to $\mathcal {P}$ and $\mathcal {P}'$. Choose a quotient map $f:P\to P'$that identifies only the edges labeled as $e$. Then $q$ and $q'\circ f$ are quotient maps that makes the same identifications, so their images $\mid\mathcal{P} \mid$ and $\mid\mathcal{P}' \mid$ are homeomorphic to each other.

I can understand the basic idea, but I am not sure why $q$ and $q'\circ f$ make the same identifications, especially when it is quite difficult to explicitly write out the equivalence relation that determines $q$ and $q'$. **Can anyone tell me how to rigorously show that $q$ and $q'\circ f$ make the same identifications? Or should I think of it as "obvious" and just proceed forward?** Any help, including a good reference that has a more detailed explanation on this topic, is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not convinced that this is the best way to explain, but at least I came up with one way to explain this; hopefully, someone will find my explanation useful.

Suppose that $e_1,e_2,\dots,e_k$ are the edges of $P$. For each $i=1,\dots ,n$, let $\gamma _i(t)$ denote the point on $e_i$ corresponding to the parameter $t\in[0,1]$ (respecting the orientation given by the presentation). The equivalence relation on $P$ corresponding to the quotient map $q$ is generated by the relation $$R=\left\{(\gamma _i(t),\gamma_j(t))\mid e_i \text{ and } e_j \text{ are labeled with the same letter}, t\in[0,1]\right\}.$$
Let $R'$ denote the relation on $P'$ that is defined in the similar way. To check that $q$ and $q'\circ f$ make the same identifications, we just need to observe that the following statements are true for $x,y\in P$:

- If $(x,y)\in R$, then $q'(f(x))=q'(f(y))$; and
- If $(f(x),f(y))\in R'$, then $q(x)=q(y)$.

These statements are not difficult to prove, at least not as hard as to directly prove that $q$ and $q'\circ f$ make the same identifications by displaying the corresponding equivalence relations explicitly.